# Web Application Firewall: alternatives to mod_security

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security, application-firewall

mod_security seems to be no longer on Debian repositories. The installation seems quite complicated. The only one I could find is [Zorp](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/zorp-gpl/overview), which seems even more complicated.

Hence I'd like to ask for up to date mod_security howto's or alternative solutions.

Many thanks!

Comment: I had a hard time finding alternatives, many related projects died possibly in favour of mod_security or firewalls off the web app layer? You could look at basic options like mod_qos which is still alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of debian are you using. libapache-mod-security is available in lenny-backports.

Comment: I'm running on Debian 5.0.6 which is up to date as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

I have CentOS, and I compiled it a month or two ago, so you may have to tweak this.
mod_security2.5 is the new version http://www.modsecurity.org/.

You need liblua readline-dev and ncurses dev as well as libxml2.

```
aptget install readline-dev ncurses-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev
```

I had to make Lua from source because CentOS doesn't have it in the default repos:

```
wget http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf lua-5.1.tar.gz
cd lua-5.1
make linux  && make install                                 
gcc -shared -o /usr/local/lib/liblua.5.1.3.so /usr/local/lib/liblua.a # Compile liblua library into a Shared Object for Apache to use
```

Mod_security2

```
wget http://www.modsecurity.org/download/modsecurity-apache_2.5.12.tar.gz
tar -xvf modsecurity-apache_2.5.12
cd modsecurity-apache_2.5.12
cd apache2
./configure
make && make install 
cd ../
mkdir /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d
cp modsecurity.conf-minimal /etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/mod_security_minimal.conf  # Copy the minimal rule set to our configuration
```

You will need to modify your Apache config to load liblua and libxml2. Notice this is LoadFile not Load Module. /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LoadFile /usr/lib/libxml2.so
LoadFile /usr/local/lib/liblua.5.1.3.so
```

And you probably want to keep your rules organized:

```
Include modsecurity.d/*.conf
```

For further configuration add your own ruleset in the modsecurity.d directory, and you can also copy any default rulesets you want from the mod_security folder extracted above under the `rules` folder.

Restarting httpd will be required.